# Qgis2Web: roll out and zipped folders in the legend

Tags: qgis, legend, qgis2web, plugins

I am using Qgis2Web in order to compose an interactive map for a website but in the legend I have many folder with layers. For users visualization I want the folders to be able to be roll out or zipped, depending on what the user wants to see, and not that every time that I expand the legend all items are visible, even the items of all the folders. How can I configure that from Qgis2web?

Here I leave an example of something similar to how I want the legend to be displayed

[image]

And here an example of how it currently looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you some advice only for openlayers export. In layers.js file layers list is written with the `var layersList` variable, you can override this command by structuring the list into groups by writing this before closing the body of your index.html file

```js
<script>
var layersList = [
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Basemap',
            layers: [
lyr_GoogleLabels_0,lyr_GoogleTerrain_1,lyr_GoogleSatellite_2,lyr_OpenStreetMap_3,lyr_SfondoBianco_4,
]}),
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'WMS Catasto',
            fold: 'close',
            layers: [
lyr_WMSCatastoFogli_5,lyr_WMSCatastoStrade_6,lyr_WMSCatastoAcque_7,lyr_WMSCatastoParticellezoom200m_8,lyr_WMSCatastoFabbricatizoom200m_9,lyr_WMSCatastoVestizionizoom100m_10,
]}),
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Vincoli e Tutele',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [
lyr_PaiEsondazioniagg2016_11,lyr_PaiFraneagg2016_12,lyr_ParchieRiserve_14,lyr_VincoloIdrogeologico_15,lyr_VincoliArcheologiciArt142m_17,lyr_GalassiniDM310785_18,lyr_BellezzeNaturaliArt136_19,lyr_ZPS_20,lyr_SIC_21,
]}),
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Cartografia generale',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [
lyr_ToponimiMonti_13,lyr_ReticoloIdrografico_16,lyr_ConfiniComunali_22,lyr_ConfiniProvinciali_23
]}),
];
</script>
```

Obviously you have to find the lyr.... names in layers.js file

This is the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you @andreaordonselli for ypur help that is the result I want for my interactive map. I will try it!!!

Comment: do you know how to add a group inside a group for legend visualization? For example I want a group call Saneamiento to be divided also into two groups one call Agua and another call Residuos each of them with their corresponding layer. I've tried to change the script you share me but it does not work. This is the script I used:

Comment: new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Agua',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [
lyr_AYSA_poligonos_fill_blcnk_1,
]}),
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Residuo',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [
lyr_AyS_CAMARCO_pol_0,
]}),
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Saneamiento',
            fold: 'open',
            group: [
group_Residuo,group_Agua,
]}),